# Windows 2008 Web edition

Tags: windows-server-2008

Can I install 
Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server Express 2008, SQL Server 2008, Subversion Server
on Windows Server Web edition 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL Server 2008 Express edition: Yes
SQL Server 2008 Web Edition: Yes
SQL Server 2008 Workgroup and higher: No (I'm like 99% sure on this part)
Subversion: Yes
Visual Studio 2010: Yes
```